# Several data visualizations on one page?

Tags: interaction-design, info-visualisation, design, charts

I have a set of visual models that can answer different questions such as:

1. How is Country A doing in x
2. What is Country A's proportion of y
3. ...

There will be approximately 5-6 questions with different charts for each.

Ideally the user could interactively navigate this by Country (and see all questions) and by "Question" (and then select country to compare).

Can you provide any links to similar applications or ideas on how to present these country-question charts in an interesting way?

Comment: http://www.app.collinsindicate.com/worldbankatlas-global/en-us - the UX isn't absolutely brilliant, but they are trying to meet the same design goals as you.

Comment: It is a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2007, this site made a big splash with its visualization of big data sets: http://www.gapminder.org/world/.

The navigation was based on data set, which could be filtered by country or region. The real innovation is that most of the info was plotted over time. Press the Play button to see how the data points change over time.

For example, if you select "CO2 Emissions Since 1820" you will not only see who got an early start on the Industrial Revolution (England), but how income relates to pollution and who had the biggest carbon footprint per capita in 2011 (The UAE, followed closely by Saudi Arabia and the USA).